# Declaring/using variables with barcode in EPL

Tags: variables, zebra-printers, epl

I am having some difficulty in using variables that I am declaring in a barcode statement using EPL (I have a zebra tlp 2844 printer).

Here is my code

```
N
q609
Q203,26

FK"GNLABEL"
FS"GNLABEL"
V00,3,N,"ENTER PROGRAM:"
V01,4,N,"ENTER YEAR:"
C0,6,N,+1,"-ENTER COUNTER VALUE:"
B10,10,0,3,1,3,50,B,**V00,V01"G"CO**
FE
FR"GNLABEL"
?
GNJ
2013
0

P1
```

When I send my file to the printer, I do not get a prompt for V00 or V01, and nothing prints out (just 1 blank label)

Answer (score 0):

Looking over your code, it seems that a few things might need to be changed.

When you are recalling the form with FR, you are not specifying the form name. It will not know which form to recall without the name.

In your form, there is a ",CO" at the end of your barcode command. I believe what you are trying to do is place the counter digit at the end, C0 (I believe your code is using the capital letter O instead of the number 0). To do this, the comma should be removed.

Try using the following code:

```
N
q609
Q203,26

FK"GNLABEL"
FS"GNLABEL"
V00,3,N,"ENTER PROGRAM:"
V01,4,N,"ENTER YEAR:"
C0,6,N,+1,"-ENTER COUNTER VALUE:"
B10,10,0,3,1,3,50,B,"GNJ2013G"C0
FE
FR"GNLABEL"
?
GNJ
2013
0
P1
```

Hopefully this helps. Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: OK, I changed my code in the original to use the variables that I am declaring..After calling the form "GNLABEL" on my FR line, I still am not able to get my label printed using the variables. The counter still doesn't work